# How to share revenue with users in android?

Tags: android, ads, revenue-sharing

In the apps that users create content, is there a way to share revenue with users when ads in their content is clicked? Is there such a platform?

Comment: Did you get any answer or workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can share ad revenue with users, Google Analytics Revenue Sharing.
you can find a quick start in [Adsense Revenue Sharing](https://developers.google.com/adsense/host/revenuesharing)

Documents goes through the necessary guidelines on where and how you can share your ad revenue with you can useres.

This includes Guidelines regarding % of revenue sharing, Which users should be eligible for the program, Do not forget to checkout their [Revenue Policy](https://developers.google.com/adsense/host/review_policy)

Comment: You need to be Adsense Host Partner for that and it is quite difficult: https://developers.google.com/adsense/host/become-a-host